# How to create sub entry points of angular using Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-workspace-configuration

my goal is to create angular library with:

1. `npx ng g library mycomp/ui/<library>` or alternatively
2. `npx ng g module mycomp/ui/<library>`

Attempt #1 with `npx ng g library`
Command to run

```
npx ng g library mycomp/ui/my-app-profile --dry-run
```

Error produced

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"mycomp/ui/my-app-profile"}
Errors:

  Data path "/name" must match pattern "^(?:@[a-zA-Z0-9-*~][a-zA-Z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-zA-Z0-9-~][a-zA-Z0-9-._~]*$".
```

Attempt #2 with `npx ng g m`

Command to run

```
npx ng g m my-app-profile --project @mycomp/ui --dry-run
```

produced

```
CREATE projects/mycomp/ui/lib/my-app-profile/my-app-profile.module.ts (198 bytes)

NOTE: The "dryRun" flag means no changes were made.
```

the problem is, the module gets created in `lib/` instead of `projects/mycomp/ui/my-app-profile/src/my-app-profile.module.ts`